# My ls -R doesn't work

Tags: c, struct, directory, ls, stat

Having issues with my ls -R implemented in C. When I run the program with command ./myls -R nothing displays, all blank:(Help needed.

```
int print_Recursive(char *dirname)

{
char fbuf [256];
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *dirp;
struct stat sbuf;

printf("\n");
dir = opendir(dirname);

while ((dirp = readdir(dir)))
{
    if(strcmp(dirp->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
       strcmp(dirp->d_name, "..") != 0)
    {
        sprintf(fbuf, "%s/%s", dirname, dirp->d_name);

    }
}
closedir(dir);


return 0;
}


int print_file(char *file, char *dir, struct stat buf, int showinode, int showlong, int showRec)
{
if (showinode)
    printf("%lld ", buf.st_ino);

if (showlong)
    print_long(file, dir, buf);

if (showRec)
    print_Recursive(dir);
else
    printf("%s\n", file);

return 0;
}
```

Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong:(

Comment: Your `print_Recursive` doesn't recurs (call itself).

Comment: I am new at C, can you please help me out? `print_Recursive(dir);` I am calling it here, isnt it?

Comment: Recursive means it would also call itself. So there would be a call to `print_Recursive` from inside `print_Recursive`. Specifically, in your `while` loop inside `print_Recursive` it should check if the file is a directory and, if it is, call `print_Recursive` on that directory. In addition, @TimLeathart points out why you have no output.

Comment: isn't this statement `if(strcmp(dirp->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
       strcmp(dirp->d_name, "..") != 0)` checks if its file or directory?

Comment: No, that just checks if the file is one of the special directory names, `'.'` or `'..'`. You need that to avoid traversing to self or to the parent directory. To tell if it's a directory, check the `d_type` as described in the [manual page for `readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir).

Comment: Not sure how to do this:(

Comment: `if (dirp->d_type == DT_DIR) ...`. You can google examples. Just Google for "readdir examples".

Comment: and then should i use `strcpy` and `strcat` to display?

Comment: Just use `printf`. You should read the manual pages for `strcpy`, `strcat`, and `prinf` to understand what they are for.

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: use the source, Luke http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c

Answer (score 0):

You use `sprintf`to store a value in `fbuf`, but you never print `fbuf` so nothing will appear. Try adding this line after the while loop:

```
printf("%s", fbuf);
```

Comment: Or just `printf(fbuf);` or even `printf("%s/%s", dirname, dirp->d_name);` since the extra buffer serves no purpose.

Comment: it worked, but it doesnt display the contents of the current directory:(